Error while converting website to webapplication on visual studio 2017
I followed the steps and successfully created the web application from website on visual studio 2017. I'm not getting any error or warning but there is message below

The JavaScript language service has been disabled for the following project(s): Application\tsconfig. These files exceeded the program size threshold: .\Application\assets\vendor\chart\Chart.js.

How to resolve this issue?
I tried adding a tsconfig.json file but that didn't work.

Your question needs more details. It is unclear what you are trying to achieve, what problems you have, and what works and what is not as expected. This phrase I followed the steps and successfully created the web application from website on visual studio 2017 doesn't explain which technologies your website initially used and to which technology you are trying to convert it. Visual Studio 2017 is not a language or technology. It is just an IDE under which you can use pretty much any language or framework.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

And both of your errors are the exact same text, so I removed the other one
